# React native view opacity with scroll Y interpolate

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set opacity dynamically based on scrollview's Y position.

I can get opacity from 1 => 0 using ...

```
opacity: this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 250],
  outputRange: [1, 0],
})
```

and ScrollView has following attribute

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
  [
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY },
      },
    },
  ],
  {
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }
)}
```

But my requirement is to get opacity to `0.5`, not `0`.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Interpolate function works with an input and output as you know.
input is the value which you want to make an interpolate on, and output is the input range's output's range. for example:
if you are scrolling and want to make some animation on 200 to 360, your input will be [200,360] (the range between 200 and 360) and if you want to change opacity from 1 to .3 your output range will be [1,0.3]. in your case :

```
opacity: this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [-, 250],
  outputRange: [1, 0.5],
})
```

Comment: of course, i tried this already, and does not work. setting to 0.5 still makes the view fully transparent unfortunately. Increasing second index of output "slows down" the animation though

Comment: added scrollview code above, this is pretty much it

Answer (score 0):

```
inputRange: [0, 150],
outputRange: [1, 0.3],
extrapolate: 'clamp',
```

Worked for me. Where `0.3` is where you want to transition to (so in your case `0.5`)